# How to set up CiviCRM on separate Drupal from primary site?

Tags: drupal

At wit's end trying to combine Civi and Open Social on the same D8 server, and wondering if I'm going about this all wrong.

How about if I have D8 running Open Social in one html directory, and Civi on D7 in another? Can I set up programmatic hooks so changes in D8 update the Civi database? I figure that way I can get up and running on Open Social for my deadline staging, get D7 glued in before going live, and maybe merge the two into D8 when Civi doesn't require elephant analgesics to work there.

I'm finding docs on multisite, but that's not it. I'm thinking two different Drupals on virtual hosts or separate server instances.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use the API from Drupal 8 to access your CiviCRM on Drupal 7, this is a set up I encounter fairly regularly.

There are a few resources explaining how this can be done conceptually:

- https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/using-civicrm-form-processor-extension-to-handle-form-submissions-from-an-external
- [How to get CiviCRM Views to work in Drupal 8 with separate CiviCRM database](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27768/how-to-get-civicrm-views-to-work-in-drupal-8-with-separate-civicrm-database)
- https://docs.civicrm.org/civiproxy/en/latest/

Comment: To add to Erik's answer, if your public site doesn't use any civicrm functionality and is only accessed by staff, here's a technique I've seen: You can make the public site d8 and share the civicrm database between the two until you figure out how to make it all d8, and then the civi db is already up-to-date. So there's three mysql databases - d7, d8, and civi. Doing this during initial install is tricky, but you can always copy/move the tables after and update civicrm.settings.php to tell it where the drupal and civi data are. So staff can use the civi functions via the d7 site.

Comment: I will come back and mark this answered once I have a chance to install some code and see how it looks. But I think, between the two of you, you’ve turned what would have been an impossible task into something that looks reasonably straightforward, Thanks!