# How can I submit WordPress forms to a REST URL?

Tags: wordpress

I've been directed here to ask this question, I've been asked if WordPress contact forms/forms can post to a REST URL rather than to the WordPress database. Now I'm not really familiar with CiviCRM tbh but we were wondering if there were any plugins that could achieve this? Any advice please.

Comment: is this because you don't want to have civi on that WP site? if so this might be part of what you need https://github.com/CiviMRF/cmrf_form_processor

Comment: there are other threads on here about using it eg https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27768/how-to-get-civicrm-views-to-work-in-drupal-8-with-separate-civicrm-database

Comment: but i may be off track. also i think the above needs various companion extensions eg https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/dataprocessor

Answer (score 1):

You can use Contact Form 7 and the [Contact Form 7 CiviCRM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-civicrm-integration/) plugins for wordpress to `POST` your forms directly to CiviCRM's REST API. There is a [blog post by Erik Hommel](https://civicrm.org/blog/erikhommel/send-wordpress-contact-form-7-data-to-civicrm-with-api) on CiviCRM.org that explains how this works.