# How to display CiviCRM Custom Fields in a Drupal 8 View

Tags: drupal-views, drupal-8

I've been not very experienced with CiviCRM. I try to get CiviCRM custom fields displayed in Views.
I've installed Drupal 8.9.3., CiviCRM 5.28.3, CiviCRM Entity 8.x-3.0-beta1.

Drupal and CiviCRM run on different databases on the same server with the same database user.
In added the array with the links to the correct database to civicrm.settings.php as described in https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/views/.

In Drupal 7, when I created a view(user) I was offered different CiviCRM fields. This doesn't happen in my Drupal 8 installation.

Besides when In try to create a view(contacts) I get the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'usr_p550866_1.civicrm_contact' doesn't exist: SELECT civicrm_contact.id AS id FROM {civicrm_contact} civicrm_contact LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0; Array ( )
```

(usr_p550866_1 is the database for Drupal)

Is this a problem with Drupal 8 or do I anything wrong?

Your help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Hi Paul - this might get marked as a Duplicate Question - does the answer here help? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31146/96

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it in settings.php not civicrm.settings.php. once you add them in settings file clear Drupal cache

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. This served the problem with the different databases,

Comment: What remains is my starting problem. I now can display the structure of custom fields in Views but I haven't found a way to display its contents. What I want is to have a view that display the content of several custom fields that belongs to a certain Durpal user. Can anybody help here?

Comment: There was probably I misconfiguration of civicrm, not everything works as expected.