# Navigation & Extension issues Civi5.8.2 & Drupal8

Tags: drupal, multisite, shoreditch, symfony, contact-layout-editor

Having installed a site with **the latest versions of Drupal8 and CiviCRM**, I connected it to a **shared CiviCRM database**.

1. I followed the "[full manual process](https://www.mydropwizard.com/blog/how-install-civicrm-drupal-8-and-why-choose-it-over-pure-drupal-crm)" of David Snopek to successfully install Drupal 8.6.4 & CiviCRM 5.8.2 !
2. Then I used [the advices of Jon G.](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26988/how-to-install-a-separated-civi-database-with-drupal-8/27830#27830) on how to separate the Drupal 8 database from my CiviCRM database.

These were great positive steps but very fast, I run into issues concerning the Navigation and several Extensions.

Concerning the **Navigation issue** the menu items are shown in a wrong alignement and they are not clicable.

[image: Navigation issue with Civi5.8.2 & Drupal8]

The **Shoreditch extension** is ON but it could not not seen in the CiviCRM settings for the Resource URLs (civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1). I manually did set the path.

On one page there is a missing image with this warning : **"civicrm Forbidden  You don't have permission to access /vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/i/Inform.gif on this server."** Can this be a clue ?

Concerning the **Extensions**, most of them works fine, like on the Drupal7  sites sharing the same CiviCRM 5.8.2 database. The most troublesome extension is the API v4(org.civicrm.api4) that handle the Contact Layout Editor (org.civicrm.contactlayout). 
This extension break the CiviCRM site : **The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.** The Drupal8 is still OK and gave this error message :

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException:
>   Unable to parse file "PATH/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.api4/services.xml".
>   in  Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->parseFileToDOM()
>   (line 386 of
>   PATH/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php).

Another point is there no Views integration settings in the **Settings - Drupal Integration**

[image]

Thanks for any help ;-)

---

EDIT (pasted from comment)

Thank you very much Jon,

This clarify the question about the position of the vendor file. **Your point of view make great sense.** It seems to be a more clean organisation and for the security reasons that you mentioned also, I do agree.

So I will then withdraw from this direction where vendor was webroot-accessible to go forward with symlinking the vendor directory into the webroot.
But when I follow the process, and at the very beginning of your [Drupal 8/CiviCRM notes](https://hq.megaphonetech.com/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_for_Drupal_8_installation_notes), with the Civi 5.8.2 there is an Error : our requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. I do not recall this error when I use the (a) method (vendor in the webroot).

But when I follow the process, and at the very beginning of your [Drupal 8/CiviCRM notes](https://hq.megaphonetech.com/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_for_Drupal_8_installation_notes), with the Civi 5.8.2 there is an Error : our requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. I do not recall this error when I use the (a) method (vendor in the webroot).

> But when I follow the process, and at the very beginning of your
>   [Drupal 8/CiviCRM notes](https://hq.megaphonetech.com/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_for_Drupal_8_installation_notes), with the Civi 5.8.2 there is an Error :
>   our requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages. I do not recall this error when I use the (a) method (vendor
>   in the webroot).
>
> ```
>    Problem 1
>     - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.8.2 requires civicrm/civicrm-cxn-rpc ~0.17.07.01 
> -> satisfiable by civicrm/civicrm-cxn-rpc[v0.17.07.01].
>     - Installation request for civicrm/civicrm-core 5.8.2 
> -> satisfiable by civicrm/civicrm-core[5.8.2].
>     - Conclusion: remove psr/log 1.1.0
>     - Conclusion: don't install psr/log 1.1.0
>     - civicrm/civicrm-cxn-rpc v0.17.07.01 requires psr/log ~1.0.0 
> -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2].
>     - Can only install one of: psr/log[1.0.0, 1.1.0].
>     - Can only install one of: psr/log[1.0.1, 1.1.0].
>     - Can only install one of: psr/log[1.0.2, 1.1.0].
>     - Installation request for psr/log (locked at 1.1.0) 
> -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.0].
>     Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
> ```

Is this a setting only that I can change in the json file of the Composer ?
Can I change the composer repository to access to the Civi 9-beta ?
*In case, of course, that the Civi 9.0 handle civicrm/civicrm-cxn-rpc ~0.17.07.01.* is handled now.

---

==> EDIT #2

After the several advices of Jon (Thanks a lot ;-) I could complete the install of **CiviCRM 5.8.2 which is now OK with Drupal 8.6.4** !

1. Install Drupal

> composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev --no-dev

2. Follow Jon G. [CiviCRM for Drupal 8 installation notes](https://hq.megaphonetech.com/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_for_Drupal_8_installation_notes)
3. If the Installation failed (at the initial stage following the David Snopek instructions) with the version psr/log 1.1.0 being too new for CiviCRM, then force with Composer to an earlier version =>

> composer require  psr/log 1.0.0

4. After that restart and complete the Installation
5. After adding the recommended lines to civicrm.settings.php, **CiviCRM works with the right menu ;-)**
6. Now the difficult part : connect to the external CiviCRM database. After disabling a few extensions I could make all the system work ! After the few extensions discussed with Jon ( **Shoreditch**, **APIv4** & Contact Layout Editor because it depends on this one) I noticed another trouble with the **General Data Protection Regulation** extension by (uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr). The contact page was white. After disabling the GDPR extension, **CiviCRM is now connected to the external database ;-)**

Thank you so much David Snopek for your work and Jon G. for your great help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple conflicting methods of installing CiviCRM with Drupal 8.  It sounds like you're either a) placing the `vendor` directory into your webroot, or b) symlinking the `vendor` directory into your webroot.

The lack of definitive instructions for D8/Civi is frustrating.  However (for security reasons) I believe the community won't accept a solution where `vendor` is webroot-accessible, which the "dsnopek full manual process" does.  Note that David Snopek does NOT use that approach himself anymore!

[Here are my Drupal 8/CiviCRM notes](https://hq.megaphonetech.com/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_for_Drupal_8_installation_notes).  Instead of installing `vendor` in webroot, I copy the JS/CSS/etc. resources only into a web-accessible directory.  Pay particular attention to the last bullet point; manually setting paths in `civicrm.settings.php` is almost certainly the solution here for Shoreditch.

Also note Shoreditch [has another problem in D8](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/issues/32) that breaks QuickSearch, but it's fixed in Civi 5.9+.  You can [backport the fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8/pull/17/files) to 5.8 or upgrade to 5.9 next week (January 2nd 2019).

As for APIv4, there's a [breaking incompatibility](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.api4/pull/99) between the Symfony version it wants and Drupal 8.  Contact Layout Editor is off the table until that's fixed.  This requires that CiviCRM be upgraded to Symfony 3+.

Comment: @Ichi If you join the ~Drupal channel on https://chat.civicrm.org, there's a "Drupal 8 to the finish line" sprint being planned for February or March by Olly Gibson.

Comment: Yes Jon, I will join the channel. If I can help, that will be w/ pleasure.

Comment: @Ichi Great!  Find me on chat as "junglebird".  Note that I am NOT suggesting you symlink your `vendor` directory into the `web` directory - this is as insecure as installing `vendor` there directly.  Instead, install `vendor` alongside your `web` directory (this is the default).  Then, per my instructions, create a directory `libraries/civicrm` under the `web` directory, and copy all assets (JS/CSS/etc.) there.

Comment: Thanks Jon and Ichi - this question and answer helped me wade through all the info out there. I've also made my own notes at https://gist.github.com/demeritcowboy/89cab9859c5db2e767fa0e1f5630214b

Comment: Glad to hear it @Demerit!  I have a backlog of documentation tasks, but I have it in mind to try to write the new definitive D8 install guide and put it in the docs.

Comment: Hello @Demerit, I also glad that this helped you. @Jon, this great news. I am looking forward for the much needed `definitive D8 install guide` ;-).

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the issue posted in your update: There's a dependency conflict between CiviCRM and some other component you have installed over which version of `psr/log` should be installed.

Both `civicrm-core` and `civicrm-cxn-rpc` specify `psr/log ~1.0.0` which means "any version starting with 1.0".  You have another package that's specifying `psr/log 1.1.0`.  I couldn't tell you which one, though you could probably figure it out by searching your `composer.lock` file.

`psr/log 1.1.0` is pretty new - about 5 weeks old.  I just [opened an issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/issues/43) for CiviCRM to support it.  My guess is that it works just fine, it just needs the `composer.json` updated.

There's probably a way to tell composer to accept the newer `psr/log` but I don't know it.  Hopefully someone else will chime in with the quick workaround!

Comment: Thanks Jon, yes the psr/log 1.1.0 version comes with Drupal  8.6.4 unfortunately . This is so hard to make CiviCRM work with Drupal ;-( I am not used to Composer but I am getting better. I use the command : "composer require psr/log 1.0.0" to be able to finish the CiviCRM installation without trouble.

Comment: Agreed @Ichi!  However, of the many problems that CiviCRM/D8 installation have, I think this one is a little more forgivable.  CiviCRM releases monthly, and Drupal 8.6.4 changed the `psr/log` minimum after the Drupal 5.8 release.  Drupal 8.6.3 doesn't have this issue.  But thanks to your pointing this out, we've already got patches in the review pipeline: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-cxn-rpc/pull/8